Covering a shapely geometry with the smallest number of equally-sized circles
Let's say i have to instruct a robot to look for an object on the floor of a house. The floor plan is expressed as a shapely geometry (containing some larger rooms separated by narrow corridors) and the robot has a cone of vision spanning N meters in front of it.
I want to implement a "dumb" approach to this search where the robot simply picks a certain number of points on the surface such that if it visits each one in order and spins in place every point of the floor will be in its field of vision at least once.
Does shapely implement some utilities to help me achieve this task? I can't simply draw a grid over the floor and visit every intersection because i might miss one of the corridors.
